# Windows phone 8 json parsing

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

What are the best possible ways to parse JSON data in Windows phone 8. I need simple and robust JSON parser library with example. Is there any inbuilt support available in C# itslef? I am using C# and XAML for my app. I need t parse my JSON data that I get from my web requests.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://json2csharp.com/ to create C# classes for json and then use [Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to deserialize ti quite easily:

```
await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<RootObject>(jsontext);
```